# How to display player.transform.position in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game on Unity3d I work on save/load game and I want to display `player.transform.position`, but it always shows `0, 0, 0`. Can't understand why

[image]

```
public GameObject player;    
private Transform playerTransform; 
//..
playerTransform = player.GetComponent<Transform>();
```

Save Data

```
PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("x" + currentActiveSlot, playerTransform.position.x);
PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("y" + currentActiveSlot, playerTransform.position.y);
PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("z" + currentActiveSlot, playerTransform.position.z);
PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

Load Data

```
Debug.Log("transform before: " + transform.position); // all time 0,0,0
playerTransform.position = new Vector3(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("x" + currentActiveSlot),
                                       PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("y" + currentActiveSlot),
                                       PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("z" + currentActiveSlot));        
Debug.Log("transform after: " + transform.position); // all time 0,0,0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are displaying transform.position which is not set anywhere.

Load Data

```
Debug.Log("transform before: " + transform.position); // all time 0,0,0
transform.position = new Vector3(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("x" + currentActiveSlot),
                                       PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("y" + currentActiveSlot),
                                       PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("z" + currentActiveSlot));        
Debug.Log("transform after: " + transform.position); // all time 0,0,0
```

or

```
Debug.Log("transform before: " + playerTransform.position); // all time 0,0,0
playerTransform.position = new Vector3(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("x" + currentActiveSlot),
                                       PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("y" + currentActiveSlot),
                                       PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("z" + currentActiveSlot));        
Debug.Log("transform after: " + playerTransform.position); // all time 0,0,0
```